# Using boost::algorithm::to_lower with std::for_each

Tags: c++, boost, std, c++98

I'm trying to compile the following:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/functional.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>

...

std::vector<std::string> names;
std::for_each(names.begin(), names.end(), std::bind(boost::algorithm::to_lower<std::string>, _1, std::locale()));
```

but I'm getting the error:

error C2664: 'void (WritableRangeT &,const std::locale &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::arg' to 'std::string &'

in Visual Studio.

What am I doing wrong?

Am I correct in saying that boost::algorithm::to_lower is seen by the compiler as a binary even though its second argument is a default value? And because of this, I need to bind.

Comment: You are using `std::bind` but saying `c++98`?

Comment: I think the reason is that you are using `boost` placeholders with `std::bind`. Using both from one namespace, it compiles for me with clang.

Comment: @bamboon Well spotted! I should be using boost::bind! I have included #define _HAS_CPP0X 0 in my main